# How to scrollToPosition RecyclerView with HORIZONTAL LinearLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, linearlayoutmanager

This code works as intended:

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(2);
```

The positioning and scroll are vertical and third item is displayed.

Now, if in the above code `VERTICAL` is replaced with `HORIZONTAL`, items are displayed horizontally and scroll is horizontal (as intended), but `setScrollToPosition(2)` doesn't work anymore.

How to `scrollToPosition` with `HORIZONTAL LinearLayoutManager`?

My XML file is mentioned below:

```
< android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvPosters"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp" >
```

Comment: You cannot see 3rd item entirely?